I think a wrong answer has been accepted for this question
which one is a better translation and seems natural in Chinese?
What do you think whether Chinese people call a button that appears on a screen a "按钮"?
Please let me know, thank you!

since I had said two weeks ago that I am completely illiterate in Chinese and I'm not learning right now, it is difficult for me to recognize the right answer and since that answer was edited by Tang Ho who has already 2186 reputations on the site, I accepted it. Anyway, I'll accept the question which has received more votes so far.

Yes. The answer is wrong, but the question itself is quite complicated, and was not phrased in the best possible way. You can suggest to the OP to reslect an answer, granted the poster is still here. However over time, users of chinese se will vote for the most useful answer.
But I think this is a good idea/path for the future of Chinese SE, instead of asking random questions, maybe a combination of questions. Not sure how others would think about this. This is the meta so i believe a discussion about this is ok.
You can follow the original post at Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to Chinese on topic here? 

What is wrong with my answer? I poster accepted another answer before and that answer is wrong.

Sorry for sounding too condescending. I didnt direct my remarks at anyone. I meant to say, it might not the best answer. But i think it is just how the SE system works. Over time, new answers will pop up and the OP will have the choice of reselecting better answers, either based on helpfulness or votes.

I don't think I can @ you, maybe it is because your username starts with Chinese. Sorry for sounding angry, I'm not, I was just asking where was wrong, if you think it was. It's ok if it is not the best answer, but I think it at least has to be a right answer, otherwise other learners may consider it is the right answer. I won't raise the problem if the answer was correct, even it was not the best.

@EmmaXL your answer is good.
